# How to create intent activity with file pick dialog?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

More exactly, how to create activity and then how to use selected path to write to removable storage?

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JtwF.png), [and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLoo.png)?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create Custom Dialog for Hint. then call intent to open specific Folder. see below code.

```
 Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");

if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file 
    // explorer app installed on your device
}
```

For custom Dialog [Material Design Dialog Lib](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)